# Converting list object into custom Map using Java 8 stream object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class "First" which contains reference to Class "Second" as list. I am trying to achieve below block in Java 8 way by using Stream (or) flap Map (or) groupingBy

```
foreach(First a: listOfFirst){
    for (Second b: a.getSecondDetails()) {
        inputMap.put(b, a);
    }
}
```

I tried below simplified way

```
listOfFirst.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> p.getSecondDetails().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p, q -> q));
```

I am missing something here, please help me out

Comment: Please Elaborate this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "remember" the `First` instance corresponding to each `Second` instance. You can do it, for example, by creating `Map.Entry` instances:

```
Map<Second,First> result =
    listOfFirst.stream()
               .flatMap(p->p.getSecondDetails()
                            .stream()
                            .map(sec -> new SimpleEntry<>(sec,p))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                         Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: This is what I looking for !!